# Estimation of a state-space model using Bayesian analysis with the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm

Tags: bayesian, metropolis-hastings

I have the following state-space model:
$$\begin{aligned}
y_t&=c+Ax_t+q_t, &q_t \sim \mathcal N(0,Q),  \\
x_t&=\mu+Bx_{t-1} + v_t, &v_t \sim \mathcal N(0,R),
\end{aligned}
$$
where the series $x_{t=1}^T$ is latent.

I am interested in estimating $\Phi=[ x_{t=1}^T, A,B,R,Q,c,\mu ]$ via Bayesian analysis using the  Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. That is, I want to estimate the following distribution:
$$
f(\Phi|y^t) \propto f(y_t|\Phi)f(\Phi).
$$
$f(y_t|\Phi)$  is a maximum likelihood function which can be constructed with the Kalman Filter algorithm. I am unsure about the second function: $f(\Phi)$ (the prior). What is the proper prior for the whole series $x_t^T$?  Also, as
$f(\Phi)=f(x_t,A,B,R,Q,c,\mu)$

I am not sure if it makes sense to have independent priors as $\mu$ and $R$ are not independent of $x_t^T$.

Comment: You don't need an explicit prior on $x_t, t=1,\dots,T$, only on $x_0$, as your second expression in the state space model in effect, writing heuristically, constructs that prior from the priors on $x_0$, $B$, and $R$.  Your parameters are $\Phi = (x_0, A, B, R, Q, c, \mu)$.  You'll still get a joint posterior for the latent $x_t$ out, though.